# Distinguish between disabled and enabled dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

We have an asp.net webform with several textboxes, dropdownlists and buttons, like the image below. At any moment, there will be several controls disabled and a few enabled.

In the webform below, DropDownList DB1 and DB2 are disabled, while DB3 isn't. How can the user visually know that DB1 & DB2 are disabled? With the textbox and the button you can see the difference.

I believe the Windows Form has a read-only property that sets the background to gray; unfortunately, that doesn't exist with the web DropDownList.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could try some CSS -- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you are using ASP.NET 4, any control that is set `Enabled = false` will be assigned a CSS class named aspNetDisabled.

You can define a styles for that CSS class, maybe something like this:

```
.aspNetDisabled {
   color: grey;
}
```

Comment: I had previously tried it, but the controls remained the same. Also, I added the CSS inline instead of using a CSS file: `.aspNetDisabled { color:Yellow; background-color:Maroon; font-style:italic; }`

Comment: I also added it in my CSS file, and the same result; the `background-color` did not change for any of the controls. I'm using .net 4. Is it possible that it may now work if it's a modalpanel?

Comment: There may be other styles interfering, maybe inline styles. You can check with you browser's debug tools (F12) which styles are being applied to the select elements rendered by the DropDownList.